# Android Studio importing aar file from repository make dependencies disappear

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I've created an android library, successfully published it on a private gradle repository, and used it in multiple projects without any problem.

Now I have to release an app for an external client, so I would like to include the library as an aar file directly inside the project.

I downloaded the aar (which I was using in the project) from the repository and imported as aar module it in Android Studio, but when updating the project a lot of dependencies disappeared.

It seems to me that don't make any sense, somebody could explain what it's going on?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I successfully imported the aar, but I have manually to add to the main project all gradle's dependencies of the library. 
There isn't really a better way?

Comment: As I understand : if it is included like a separate module - it should have a build.gradle where you can manage your dependcies.

Answer (score 0):

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the nested (or [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo **you have to specify the dependencies also in your project**.

Using a **maven repository** you will not have the same issue because in this case gradle downloads all the dependencies reading the pom file.